# web service deployment error

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, netbeans-8

I have a simple web service that was work just fine..two days ago
now I'm trying to complete my code but I have a strange issue
some time I can clean and build the project but when I try to test the web service I've got an error message that I can't test the web service and make sure that I clean-build it and the service has to be deployed (which I already done)

some time I've got this error message on my server log file

> org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider>)]

does any one can help my to figure this out
I'm using Netbeand 8.0 and glassfish 4.0

Comment: can you post your pom.xml; you most likely have a dependency conflict similar to this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052300/dependency-exception-when-deploying-maven-project

Comment: where can I find that pom.xml. I search on my web application folder and didn't find it

Comment: I assumed you're using maven to build your web service.  Are you using maven?  If so, your pom.xml file will be in the root dir of your application.

Comment: No, I'm using Java Web not maven