# com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException

Tags: rest, maven, jersey, glassfish

I am new to REST webservices and I am trying to build a webservice using jersey to upload a file. When deploying, i get this error

```
Artifact RestTest:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI definition failure:WELD-000071: Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.DefaultRespondingContext. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I created the project using this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp \
                -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
                -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=RestTest -Dpackage=com.test \
                -DarchetypeVersion=2.27
```

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.0-m05-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m05-2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052300/dependency-exception-when-deploying-maven-project) answer, i've changed to scope to 'provided', but it isn't working.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1) Don't mix Jersey versions 2) If you are running on Glassfish, then all your Jersey dependencies should be in a provided scope, as Glassfish already has all of them.

Comment: now I have the following error:
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.test.FileUpload.uploadTxt(java.io.InputStream) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.test.FileUpload, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@61f9e407]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30653012/2587435