# glassfish exception while deploying .war file

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy my maven project to Glassfish 4 but I get the following exception when it fails to deploy

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type
>   [Ref] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point
>   [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of
>   [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.UriRoutingContext(Ref,
>   ProcessingProviders)]. Please see server.log for more details.

In `server.log`

```
[2018-09-05T12:24:25.251+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=100 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134065251] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting WEB-INF/classes/com/common/core/config/security/CustomPermissionEvaluator.class of size 4615
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:25.267+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=100 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134065267] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting WEB-INF/classes/com/common/core/uploader/web/util/UploaderSetting.class of size 3763
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:25.313+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=100 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134065313] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting WEB-INF/classes/com/common/templatemanager/web/controller/TemplateManagerBCtrl.class of size 8345
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:25.366+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=100 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134065366] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting WEB-INF/classes/com/paytag/invoice/web/controller/InvoiceFCtrl.class of size 14667
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:25.382+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=100 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134065382] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting WEB-INF/classes/com/paytag/settlement/domain/SettlementResultToJson.class of size 5164
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:26.415+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134066415] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/telegram/telegrambots/updatesreceivers/DefaultBotSession$ReaderThread.class of size 9780
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:26.426+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=103 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1536134066426] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/telegram/telegrambots/api/objects/Message.class of size 12390
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:26.747+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134066747] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:27.040+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134067040] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting javax.swing.JComponent]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:27.131+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134067131] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting javax.swing.JTable]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:27.145+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134067145] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting javax.swing.JComponent]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:33.031+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134073031] [levelValue: 900] [[
  AS-CDI-005]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:35.587+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1536134075587] [levelValue: 800] [[
  12:24:35.578 [admin-listener(6)] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:35.649+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1536134075649] [levelValue: 800] [[
  12:24:35.649 [admin-listener(6)] INFO org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension - Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:35.782+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134075782] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverters$CharacterProvider because of underlying class loading error: Type [unknown] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.]]

[2018-09-05T12:24:36.215+0430] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=137 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1536134076215] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
    ... 58 more
]]
```

and this is my `pom.xml` file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<artifactId>cms</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<!-- core properties -->
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aopalliance.version>1.0</aopalliance.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <bootstrap.version>3.3.6</bootstrap.version>
    <jquery.version>2.2.3</jquery.version>
    <log4j.version>2.7</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <oracle.version>10.2.0.4.0</oracle.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <hickariCp.version>2.4.7</hickariCp.version>
    <jasypt.version>1.9.2</jasypt.version>
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>


        <!--Using this plugin for generating query dsl classes-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
                            <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                            <querydsl.prefix>Q</querydsl.prefix>
                            <querydsl.suffix></querydsl.suffix>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- repository to get dependencies -->
<!-- <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>spring-releases</id>
     <name>Spring Releases</name>
     <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>-->

<dependencies>

    <!-- spring framework dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- aopalliance dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>${aopalliance.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- thymeleaf java template engine dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- webjars for client side scripts-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JPA & DB & Hibernate dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mail dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- servlet dependency[coockie etc...]-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- inject annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>${hickariCp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.bluejoe2008</groupId>
        <artifactId>elfinder-servlet-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>${jasypt.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the Server log as suggested?

Comment: @Jens I edit my question by server.log

Comment: Which Java Version do you use for compiling and for runtime?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: can you Show your pom.XML? Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052300/dependency-exception-when-deploying-maven-project

Comment: add just `pom.xml` file content

Comment: can you Change scope of `<artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>` to provided, I am not sure but i think this is provided by glassfish

Comment: @Jens I also think that the problem occurs from a already provided dependency. As I remember javax.servlet-api is provided, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

That is a Glassfish bug, For solved this bug should delete all file and folder in `generated` and `osgi-cache` folder in `\glassfish\domains\domain1` directory and after that, you only need restart your glassfish server and deploy again.